# Is Java for OSX 2013-005 from apple a JDK6, or just a JRE?

Tags: java

I'm setting up my android development environment, and could run all my configurations (eclipse + android sdk) with either jdk from oracle,or java for osx 2013-005 from apple.

when I installed Java for OSX, I can run all jdk command line tools,like javac, jstat, jmap, etc.

I am confusing what Java for OSX 2013-005 is. Is it a JDK6 customized by apple, or just a JRE6 with removed applet and webstart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the JDK as noted in the path /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk it installs into , and also seeing what files are installed there.

As far as I understand the removal does not change Java but removes plugins from browsers

However I would use the later JDK for Java 7 from Oracle as there are some improvements in the environment and language as per Oracle's [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html)